# How to reinstall squid on ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, squid

So, I installed squid and while removing squid I accedentally deleted the /etc/squid/ folder . Now I can't install squid again. How can I install squid now.
output of `apt-get install squid`

```
Selecting previously unselected package libecap3:amd64.
(Reading database ... 235907 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libecap3_1.0.1-3ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libecap3:amd64 (1.0.1-3ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package squid.
Preparing to unpack .../squid_3.5.12-1ubuntu7.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking squid (3.5.12-1ubuntu7.3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu17) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.35-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libecap3:amd64 (1.0.1-3ubuntu3) ...
Setting up squid (3.5.12-1ubuntu7.3) ...
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.squid
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link

/sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib32/nvidia-375/libEGL.so.1 is not a symbolic link
```

Then if I run `squid`

```
FATAL: Unable to open configuration file: /etc/squid/squid.conf: (2) No such file or directory
Squid Cache (Version 3.5.12): Terminated abnormally.
CPU Usage: 0.012 seconds = 0.004 user + 0.008 sys
Maximum Resident Size: 45136 KB
Page faults with physical i/o: 0
```

Comment: **Why** can't you install squid again? Whats the output of `sudo apt-get install squid` ?

Comment: well I tried to install it, and it goes without much error, but then there is no squid.conf file in the /etc/squid/ folder

Comment: And did you try launching squid and then checking the exsitence of such file **after** that. Whats the output of `sudo updatedb && ls -lAh /etc/squid` ?

Comment: output is "total 0"

Comment: Hoe exactly are you invoking squid, post  the exact command you are using

Comment: You need to remove squid completely first then reinstall. Did you follow tso's answer?

Comment: I ran `apt-get remove` before reinstalling

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try remove squid with confs:

```
sudo apt purge squid
```

and after that install again:

```
sudo apt install squid
```

Answer (score 0):

doesn't work for me.  All I get is

sudo apt-get install squid
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
squid is already the newest version (3.5.12-1ubuntu7.8).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up squid (3.5.12-1ubuntu7.8) ...
update-rc.d: error: initscript does not exist: /etc/init.d/squid
dpkg: error processing package squid (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 squid
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I've tried re-installing, removing, purging, and everything returns an error.

Linuxmint (based on Ubuntu 16-04) cannot repeat CANNOT remove the basic squid package